# How to unpack only values from nested dict in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, argument-unpacking

I have the following code

```
mydict = {
    "key": {
        "k1": "v1",
        "k2": "v2",
    }
}
for k, (v1, v2) in mydict.items():
```

`v1` and `v2` actaully equals to `k1` and `k2`, is there a way to extract `v1` and `v2` with any unpacking syntax?

I tried to search for unpacking syntax but found nothing

Comment: Not directly, iterating/unpacking a dictionary works on its **keys**. You can use a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

No need to complicate on trying to unpack values. Here is a workaround

```
for k, (v1, v2) in mydict.items():
    print("Access the values for the key:", k, "--->", mydict[k][v1], mydict[k][v2])
```

output:

```
Accessing the values for the key: key ---> v1 v2
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible like this:

```
mydict = {
    "key": {
        "k1": "v1",
        "k2": "v2",
    }
}

for v1, v2 in mydict.popitem()[1].values():
    print(v1, v2)
```